# Reading files from two different directories

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following scrip which  reads files from two different directories. With the first set of files I do some stuff. With the other set of files(.txt) from the other directory I read each line. Everything is working fine right now except for the fact that I have to include quotation marks in order for the scrip to work. If I do not include them it only reads the files from the first directory.

This is how I am running it

bash move.sh "profile/generate/work/generate_profiles_output/merged_profiles/profiles_ * .avro"  "prod/mp/incoming/meta/files/*.txt"

```
#!/bin/bash

AVROFILES=$1
FILES=$2
#reading every avro file
for avrofile in ${AVROFILES}
do

   //do some stuff with the avrofile

   #reading the files 
   for f in  $FILES
   do
       #reading every line in on from the file
       while read line
       do

       done <"$f"

   done
done
```

Comment: There is a space in `profiles_ * .a`. If not quoted, field splitting occurs on the space and expansion of the files occurs before the script begins leaving only the first file read.

Comment: Using double quotes is de-facto standard for reasonable handling of variables. Simple whitespace will break your script. Always quote your variables. Read: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting

Comment: Every variable that can be quoted in this script as written *is* quoted. The arguments to this script are quoted so the variable expansions must not be to have the globs expanded correctly.

Comment: What's the problem here exactly? Is the issue that you need to quote the arguments to the script when you call it since otherwise your arguments aren't what you expect them to be?

Comment: Try setting IFS to not include a space first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass quoted patterns to the shell as arguments; instead, pick a non-file separator to distinguish between the two sets of files. (Here, I'm using `:::`, which GNU `parallel` uses for similar purposes.)

```
$ bash move.sh profile/generate/work/generate_profiles_output/merged_profiles/profiles_ *.avro ::: prod/mp/incoming/meta/files/*.txt
```

In your script, you'll scan the arguments, putting everything prior to `:::` in one array, and everything after in a second array.

```
while (( $# > 0 )); do
    f=$1
    shift
    if [[ $f = ::: ]]; then
        break
    fi
    AVROFILES+=( "$f" )
done

FILES=( "$@" )

for avrofile in "${AVROFILES[@]}"
do

   # do some stuff with the avrofile

   # reading the files 
   for f in  "${FILES[@]}"
   do
       # reading every line in on from the file
       while read line
       do

       done <"$f"

   done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is probably the easiest way to do it. Without the quotation marks, the asterisks are evaluated and the script gets two lists of file names.

Example: The script lists all the arguments:

```
$ cat files.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

i=0

for arg; do
    let i++
    echo \$$i is $arg
done

$ ./files.sh test-00* test-01*
$1 is test-000.delme
$2 is test-001.delme
$3 is test-002.delme
$4 is test-003.delme
$5 is test-004.delme
<snip>

$ ./files.sh "test-00*" "test-01*"
$1 is test-000.delme test-001.delme test-002.delme test-003.delme test-004.delme test-005.delme test-006.delme test-007.delme test-008.delme test-009.delme
$2 is test-010.delme test-011.delme test-012.delme test-013.delme test-014.delme test-015.delme test-016.delme
```

Comment: In general, his approach does not permit file names containing whitespace or other characters interpreted specially by the shell.

Comment: You can use single quotation marks, that disables the interpretation of the contents.

Comment: That prevents parameter expansion in the quoted string, which is not the issue.